# Date Difference in Hours Datetime format - Mulesoft

Tags: datetime, dataweave, mule4

Need help. I have a datetime format which is received from the query parameter as

```
StartTime = 2021-02-20T08:33:34+0000

EndTime = 2021-03-15T04:11:56+0000
```

I need to get the difference in hours and I am unable to perform it. Need help please.

Tried the below DW, did not work. As there is T in between and +0000 is unable to parse it.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var dateTime1 = payload."Start Time Stamp" as Date {format:"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:SSSZ"}
var dateTime2 = payload."End Time Stamp" as Date {format:"yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:SSSZ"}
--- 
(dateTime2 - dateTime1).hours
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to represent the timezone offset +0000 with ZZ.

**Script:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var dateTime1 = "2021-02-20T08:33:34+0000" as DateTime {"format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"}
var dateTime2 = "2021-03-15T04:11:56+0000" as DateTime {"format":"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"}
---
(dateTime2 - dateTime1) as Number {unit: "hours"}
```

**Output:**

```
547
```

Comment: @Kaushik - please accept the answer in case it has helped you , so that it can help folks looking for a similar solution in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help salim, I tried with XX and it worked, let me try with ZZ and let you know :)

Comment: Sure. As well let me know if we need to update the answer or otherwise would be great if you can accept this as the answer.

Comment: Doesn’t look like it.. I think you need to select the answer provided as the accepted one. It shows a green check mark once you have done the needful, next to it.